# How to publish Blazor WebAssembly app without unwanted files?

Tags: asp.net, cpanel, publish, blazor-webassembly

I want to publish my Blazor WebAssembly app using file system and CPanel, but unsure of the steps and the settings. I am using File System method

[image]

**Which settings should I select here?**
[image]

Also, I have published this and received these files

[image]

How di I publish without the .br and .gz file extensions?